# How do comment @replies work?

Tags: support, comments, faq-proposed

In a comment under my questions somebody used first name only `@Ivoxzy` instead of using the users full name `@Ivoxyz FFlipse`

Is the correct user going to informed about this message that was address to him/her?

Comment: Are you daring me to change my username?

Comment: @Ivo: I wouldn't dare :-0 Used your name, changed it so you wouldn't be notified. Do you want me to change it?

Comment: No, I find it highly entertaining ;-)

Answer (score 26, accepted):

> @Ivoxzy instead of using the users full name @Ivoxyz FFlipse

Yes. Why? [These are rules](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/43019/how-do-comment-replies-work/43020#43020) for comment @replies to work:

<sup><sup>stolen from MSO answer</sup></sup>

---

> You can use *@name* syntax anywhere in your comment to reply to a
>   specific user. This will notify that user in their [![global
>   inbox](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gFSVY.png) global
>   inbox](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/09/new-global-inbox/). There
>   is no notification through email.
>
> In short:
>
> - See [comment
>     replies](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/editing-help#comment-reply) in
>     the Markdown help.
>
> Some more detail:
>
> - The first author of the question or answer will always be notified
>     of any new comment.
> - You can explicitly notify **one (1)** other commenter or editor, by
>     using *@name*, where *name* is the username with all spaces removed.
> - Single trailing punctuation such as a dot, comma or colon is
>     ignored, like *@name, yes* works, but *@name... no* does not.
> - Things like
>     [*@op*](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/52368/does-op-also-notify-the-op),
>     [*@downvoter*](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/37090/feature-request-downvoter-sends-a-notification-to-all-downvoters-for-your-post)
>     or
>     [*@all*](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75142/is-all-comment-supported)
>     have no special meaning.
> - If a user comments on their own post and there is only one person
>     who has previously commented, then that person is [also
>     notified](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/82134/micro-refinement-to-notifications-for-comments-of-others-posts)
>     if *@name* is forgotten.
>
> And
>   [all](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1093/make-recent-activity-and-responses-show-new-comments-on-questions-answers-i-have/35913#35913)
>   [details](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/36026/what-is-the-syntax-of-username-in-comments-when-username-has-spaces/36048#36048)
>   that make this work:
>
> 1. Notifications apply to the author, commenters, and
>      [editors](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/36052/allow-post-editor-to-see-comments-directed-at-him/36055#36055)
>      of the question or answer that you are commenting on—users not in that
>      list cannot be notified. You can also notify a ♦ moderator who closed
>      the question. The question and answers are all considered
>      independently.  For example, if Alice was the author of, commented on,
>      or edited the question or her answer, then you cannot notify her by
>      commenting on Bob's answer (unless Alice *also* participated in that
>      answer), and vice versa.
> 2. You must include *@name*, where *name* is a reasonable match to a
>      user's current display name.  Users who have not set a display name in
>      their profile are not notified.
> 3. If the first word in the display name is at least three characters
>      long, then there must be a starts-with, case-insensitive match of at
>      least three characters in the display name.  This means *@a* and *@ab*
>      will never match anyone,
>      [unless](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/61960/allow-for-comment-reply-to-usernames-with-less-than-three-characters-in-first-wor/75809#75809)
>      a user uses a first word that is only two characters. Like: *@Jo* will
>      notify Jo Miller, but not John, and *@B.* will notify B. Gates, but
>      not B.Gates. Users with a display name of just one or two characters
>      are unnotifiable. If there are more than three characters in *@name*,
>      then all given characters must match (neither *@alix* nor
>      *@aliceinwonderland* will match user Alice).
> 4. Matching is performed in reverse chronological order, so if five
>      people named John are participating, *@john* will match the most
>      recent John. (Use the next rule to differentiate.)
> 5. Spaces are removed *from the display names* for matching purposes.
>      So to match Peter Smith you may use *@pet*, *@peter*, *@peters*, or
>      *@petersmith*.  The last two are useful if Peter Jones is also
>      participating, who can then be distinguished using *@peterj*. However,
>      no spaces are allowed in the *@name* itself. Like to notify P Smith,
>      one must use *@psm* or *@psmith*. (Here *@P Smith* would be handled as
>      just *@P*, which is too short.) Single quotes, dots, dashes and
>      underscores should
>      [not](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/51911/the-dot-in-username-within-first-3-character-preventing-from-comment-replies/51913#51913)
>      be removed.
> 6. Special characters [are
>      replaced](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/48968/peter-works-for-peter/49409#49409)
>      with their simple equivalent. To reply to Piëre you can use both
>      *@piëre* and *@piere*. And to reply to Jörg you could use *@jorg*,
>      [but
>      not](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/89051/joerg-works-for-jorg)
>      *@joerg*.
> 7. Comments containing more than one *@name* [are
>      blocked](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/2094/should-we-discourage-the-user-of-multiple-redundant-username-pings/2615#2615)
>      unless they contain a backtick `` ` ``. In the latter case, only the
>      first name mentioned using the *@name* syntax will be
>      [notified](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2035/notify-user-when-their-name-is-mentioned-in-comment/35914#35914).
>      For example, *@alice @bob Hi!`* will notify Alice (if she has
>      participated in that post), but not Bob.
> 8. An exception is the case when the first *@name* either matched
>      nobody, or matched the post's author (and thus isn't necessary); in
>      this case, the next *@name* will be checked.
> 9. When editing a comment within its limited editing period, if you
>      change or add *@name*, [the notification may or may not reach the new
>      recipient](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/40989/will-edited-comments-reach-addressees/74781#74781)
>      depending on timing.
> 10. The first author of the question or answer will always be notified
>       of any new comment. There is no need to use *@name* to notify them.
>       (You may still use it for clarity, if needed; however if only you and
>       the author have been commenting on the post so far, the *@name* will
>       be automatically removed from the beginning of the comment, as it adds
>       no value.)
> 11. The notification must begin with a space or be at the start of the
>       comment. For example, you [cannot use
>       markup](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/39/whats-your-favourite-quote-about-programming/1079#comment-19850)
>       such as italics.
> 12. Single trailing punctuation such as a dot, comma or colon is
>       ignored. Like *@name, yes* works, but *@name... no* [does
>       not](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/88631/why-was-i-not-notified/88639#88639).
>       (Though a dot is valid in a username, the last dot [is removed for
>       matching](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75811/using-user-name-colon-to-refer-to-a-user-in-comments/75812#75812),
>       so *@St* will notify St. although only two characters are used.)
> 13. The notification only works for the username that [is
>       current](http://chat.meta.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/481203#481203)
>       at the time the comment is submitted, not any previous username(s) the
>       target may have had.
>
> The exact matching rules are not documented, but extensive tests
>   performed on 30 August 2011 indicate that the following algorithm
>   is used:
>
> - Take the first word immediately following the `@`, where the word
>     boundary is determined by a space, a character not valid in user names
>     (such as `: , / ! ?`) or the end of the comment.
> - Remove one trailing dot `.` from the resulting string if applicable
>     (and if the string has more than two characters).
> - If the remaining string  ends in `'` or `'s`, remove that piece from
>     the string.
> - The resulting string will be matched against the user name with
>     spaces removed.
>
> Example: The comment ends with `@O'Conner's.)`. The word immediately
>   following the `@` is `O'Conner's.` since `'` and `.` are valid in user
>   names. Then the trailing dot is removed, and finally the `'s` is
>   removed, resulting in `O'Conner`.
>
> Some examples of supported notifications:
>
> - `@name some text`
> - `@name: some text`
> - `@name. Some text`
> - `@name, some text`
> - `some text, @name`
> - `some text, @name, more text`
> - `Some text, @name.`
> - `This is mentioned in @name's comment.`
> - `@P.` for both P. Smith and P. Jones (whoever commented most
>     recently), but not P.Smith nor P.Jones. Likewise, `@P. Smith` is
>     handled as `@P.`, so also matches P. Smith or P. Jones.
> - `@psm` or `@psmith` for P Smith
> - `@peters` or `@peterj` for Peter Smith or Peter Jones respectively
>
> Examples that will **not** trigger notifications:
>
> - `@name...`
> - `abc@name`
> - `*@name*`
> - `*@name:*`
> - `[@name](http://some-url)`
> - `@[name](http://some-url)`
> - `@P Smith`

Comment: the "stolen from MSO answer" bit is quite a small print.

Comment: +1 for stealing xD