# Comment @replies cannot see the names after posting?

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, comments

I do not understand this and am well aware of [this post](https://meta.superuser.com/questions/2081/how-do-comment-replies-work) but it does not address my issues. On stackoverflow I can just write

@iznogood love your post!

and I will see the comment as:

@iznogood love your post!

But here on superuser I only see:

love your post!

So my question is: Is the name saved and is the commentor notified or am I victim of some bug?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

@pinging in comments is a bit complicated. There's a [full description on Meta Stack Overflow](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/43019/how-do-comment-replies-work/43020#43020).

What's probably happening in this case is this:

> - The first author of the question or answer will always be notified of any new comment. There is no need to use @name to notify them. (You may still use it for clarity, if needed; however **if only you and the author have been commenting on the post so far, the @name will be [automatically removed](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/97098/eeeeek-what-happened-to-my-salutation/97099#97099) from the beginning of the comment**, as it adds no value.)

Comment: Ah! That explains it. Missed that part. Thanks!! +1 accepted everything.

Comment: This can't be used to bypass the character requirement, right?

Comment: @damryfbfnetsi no it cannot.

Comment: @nhinkle Just tried it. Even though the little bar at the bottom says that there are enough characters, once the comment is submitted, the character check is rerun again after stripping, and if the text after stripping is less than 15 characters, you'll get an error.

Comment: @damryfbfnetsi right, which is why I said it cannot be used to bypass the requirement.